# Google Hangouts - Can not send or receive MMS

Tags: sms, mms, google-hangouts, apn

About 2 weeks ago, I updated CyanogenMod on my device, and Google Hangouts, and began experiencing this problem. I did an immediate restore from before my update, and there was no change. I can not send or receive any MMS's on my device. When I get an MMS, I am shown a message containing the details of the message, like the time stamp, and the size of the message, along with a prompt to download the message, however it downloads forever.

When trying to send picture messages, via MMS or Hangouts, connected to either 4G LTE, or WiFi, it sends forever, and never goes through.

In Hangouts, I click `Menu -> SMS -> APNs`, and the list is empty. Clicking `Menu -> Reset to Default` does absolutely nothing.

Is there anything that I can do to get support back for sending MultiMedia Messages?

> Device: LG G2
>   Network: Verizon
>   Hangouts Version: 2.0.303
>   Android ROM: CyanogenMod 11
>   Kernel: 3.4.0-CM+
>   Android Version: 4.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A family member also has the same device, and also uses hangouts, so I was able to copy the APN information from him.

For any future reference, I got MMS to work again by adding these recods to the Google Hangouts APN List.

> Name: LTE - Verizon CBS
>   MMSC: http://mms.vtext.com/servlets/mms
>   MMS Proxy: not set
>   MMS Port: not set
>   MCC: 311
>   MNC: 480

And

> Name: EHRPD - Verizon CMS
>   MMSC: http://mms.vtext.com/servlets/mms
>   MMS Proxy: not set
>   MMS Port: not set
>   MCC: 311
>   MNC: 480